# Excel VBA Workbook_open event handler required

Tags: excel, vba

I have reference data in columns A and B on *Sheet2* of my `WorkBook`. I have a blank sheet - *Sheet1* - which i need to fill from my database.

I want to use Excel VBA to fill *Sheet1* based on data in columns A and B in *Sheet2*.

I use the reference data by.

- I populate values in column A in *Sheet1* from DB.
- I check if the values stored in sheet 1, column A exist in *Sheet2* column A,
- If so, I populate into sheet 1 column B, the corresponding data i've found in *Sheet2* column B.

Comment: There is a Workbook_Open event in Excel - so what is the question here?

Comment: See [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) for a good reference on VBA events

Answer (score 3):

- Open [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), do alt + F11 that will open the IDE.
- In the right hand window should see vba project and in brackets the name of the excel book you have open.
- At the bottom of the list of sheets is an object called `ThisWorkbook`, right click it, and select *View Code*.
- At top of should see two combo boxes, right hand one should say *General* click on it and select `Workbook` from the list.

This should give you the following

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 End Sub
```

This is the event that is fired each time the work book is opened.  Now you will need to add code to reference the sheets in the workbook.

Here is some methods for how to reference sheets in vba [Reference sheets](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/967).  Next step will be to refer to the cells in the sheets see - > [excel ranges](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referring_to_ranges_in_your_vba_code/) as an example.